# How can i limit and debug system root mail madness?

Tags: postfix

my server decided to send out mails by the hundred thousands yesterday.

The mail seem to have all the same size=670:

```
grep size=670 mail.log | wc -l
647049
```

Most of the mails seem to go to root

```
grep "to=<root@" syslog.1 | wc -l
193856
```

There is only one other recipient (me) as checked by:

```
grep "to=" syslog.1 | cut -f5 -d: | cut -f1 -d, | sort -u
```

The syslog shows that after a while my provider complains about mail quota exceeded.

```
grep "quota" syslog.1 | wc -l
384818
```

**How can i configure that the system itself will stop sending repeated mails of same size and content after a reasonable amount of repetitions - e.g. 100 or 1000?**

**Where can i find out what single example of the mail would look like?**
At this time i don't know what kind of message the system is trying to send.

At this time i had to stop postfix as a workaround.

**How can i find out the culprit of the mail while postfix is stopped/disabled?**

Comment: Have you tried to put a `.forward` in the root-home dir? Or a `root: "| /a/script/that/handles/mail` in `/etc/aliasses` (run `newaliasses` afterwards)?

Comment: No - i faintly remember that such options exist. I assume no out of the box solution is known to you but you consider a suitable script feasible?

Comment: There are some throttling options, as explained in https://serverfault.com/questions/110919/postfix-throttling-for-outgoing-messages. Don't know if that works for you. Anyway, you will need to know what is in the messages. It is a sign that something is wrong, and you need to correct that (and not just throttle the messages)

Comment: log should show the recipient. If they are all different, then most likely spammers. All the same indicates a runaway process or DOS attack.

Comment: thx - recipient shows always root so i am not too worried. The server will be switched off after this weekend anyway so after finding out what went wrong I might even not have to fix things but just take note (and report here :-). The new server might have better protection then .